# rewrite rule not working gives Not Found The requested URL .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

---

Please check the .htaccess code below  /contact , /services, /galleria, /aboutus not working dont know why, other rules are working like /sufi etc  ... kindly throw some light

---

#Test.

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /


#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
#RewriteRule .* index.php?ua=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}&https=%{HTTPS} [L]

RewriteRule ^content/profile/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ ?ref=content&type=profile&id=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/list/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ ?row=$1&s$2 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^contactus/$ ?ref=contactus 
RewriteRule ^aboutus/$ ?ref=aboutus 
RewriteRule ^services/$ ?ref=services 


RewriteRule ^code33/$ ?ref=code33 
RewriteRule ^solar/$ ?ref=solar 
RewriteRule ^sufi/$ ?ref=sufi 
RewriteRule ^fast/$ ?ref=fast 

RewriteRule ^greet/$ ?ref=greet
RewriteRule ^deviser/$ ?ref=deviser
RewriteRule ^printing/$ ?ref=printinggate
RewriteRule ^wreet/$ ?ref=wreet

#RewriteRule ^galleria-online-store-peshawar-pakistan/$ ?ref=store
RewriteRule ^galleria/$ ?ref=store

RewriteRule ^bollywood-movies/$ ?ref=cinema
RewriteRule ^bollywood/$ ?ref=cinema

RewriteRule ^ulama/$ ?ref=ulama
RewriteRule ^visa-house/$ ?ref=visahouse
#RewriteRule ^visa-house-visit-business-student-visa-work-permit/$ ?ref=visahouse

#RewriteRule ^mobile-android-apps/$ ?ref=mobilola
RewriteRule ^mobilola/$ ?ref=mobilola
```

**/contact , /services, /galleria, /aboutus not working dont know why, other rules are working like /sufi etc  ... kindly throw some light  **

Comment: Welcome Sufi - please read how to ask a good question - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For example "In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself."

Comment: SO is a free volunteer service so complaining about not getting an answer to a badly worded question in 30mins is not a good way to build reputation and get started on this site.

Comment: i heard very much good and quick responsive about stackoverflow .... i think i was wrong in expectation ....

Comment: i have found the solution my self ,  i have to remove the last slashes before $ sign ...

Comment: Well done Sufi. You can post your own solution to a question - see here for more info - http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. Just wait 48 hours before you accept it.

Comment: thanks dear ... i will look that link ...